# Sign differences in spectral decomposition in NumPy

Tags: linear-algebra, python, eigensystem, numpy, spectral-method

I am trying to understand an example from a book, but I seem to get different answers depending on which spectral decomposition function I use in NumPy.

I am trying to find a spectral decomposition $W V W^\top$ of a given symmetric matrix $G$ using NumPy functions `eig` and `eigh`, where the latter is for symmetric matrices (which $G$ is):

- `eig` returns columns arranged in a different order from the answer in the book.
- `eigh` returns a matrix similar to that in the book, but with a different sign in columns $2$ and $4$.

Are these matrices equivalent? They yield different results in downstream use. Any help is appreciated.

```
G = np.array([[-0.55,  0.3  , 0.   , 0.    ,0.25],
              [ 0.3 , -0.95 , 0.   , 0.4   ,0.25],
              [ 0.  ,  0.   ,-0.55 , 0.3   ,0.25],
              [ 0.  ,  0.4  , 0.3  ,-0.95  ,0.25],
              [ 0.25,  0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25  ,-1.  ]])

v1,w1 = np.linalg.eigh(G)
v2,w2 = np.linalg.eig(G)

print w1
array([[ 0.224,  0.224,  0.5  , -0.671,  0.447],
       [-0.671,  0.224, -0.5  , -0.224,  0.447],
       [-0.224,  0.224,  0.5  ,  0.671,  0.447],
       [ 0.671,  0.224, -0.5  ,  0.224,  0.447],
       [ 0.   , -0.894, -0.   ,  0.   ,  0.447]]))

print w2
array([[-0.447, -0.671, -0.5  ,  0.224, -0.224],
       [-0.447, -0.224,  0.5  , -0.671, -0.224],
       [-0.447,  0.671, -0.5  , -0.224, -0.224],
       [-0.447,  0.224,  0.5  ,  0.671, -0.224],
       [-0.447,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.894]]))

"Answer in book"
array([[ 0.224, -0.224,  0.5  ,  0.671,  0.447],
       [-0.671, -0.224, -0.5  ,  0.224,  0.447],
       [-0.224, -0.224,  0.5  , -0.671,  0.447],
       [ 0.671, -0.224, -0.5  , -0.224,  0.447],
       [ 0.   ,  0.894, -0.   ,  0.   ,  0.447]]))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $w_k$ be the k-th column of W (the kth eigen-vector) and $v_k$ be the k-th element of v (the kth eigen-value).  Then we can write:
$$ G = \sum_k w_k v_k w_k^T $$
which, element-wise, is equivalent to:
$$ G_{i,j} = \sum_k v_k w_{i,k} w_{j,k} $$
where the indices are column-major.
Since we always get $w_k$ twice, an overall sign on a column of $W$ cancels.
Since the sum over $k$ can occur in any order, the order of the columns of $W$ also doesn't matter as long as the elements of $v$ are in the same order.

If they are yielding different results down-stream, you likely have an error.  Were you consistent with using `v1` with `w1` and `v2` with `w2`?  `v1` and `v2` should have the same elements but a different order.  Neither `eig` nor `eigh` guarantee an ordering of the eigenvalues.